# Updating Record in C Language

Tags: c, file, updates

Can somebody help me with this code. When I try this code it doesn't work at all. I've very less experience in working with files in C Language. Please help me to solve this

Here is the structure

```
struct passenger
{
    char airline[20];
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char gender;
    char clas[10];
    int seatNo;

}e;
```

Here is the function to insert the record

```
oid reserve()
{
    int airline, clas;
    printf("\nSelect your flight:");
    printf("\n1. PIA\n2. Shaheen\n3. Air Blue\n\nEnter Choice:");
    scanf("%d", &airline);
    if (airline == 1)
        strcpy(e.airline, "\nPIA");
    else if (airline == 2)
        strcpy(e.airline, "\nShaheen");
    else if (airline == 3)
        strcpy(e.airline, "\nAirBlue");

    printf("\nEnter Name:");
    scanf("%s", &e.name);

    printf("\nEnter Age:");
    scanf("%d", &e.age);

    printf("\nEnter Your Gender (M/F): ");
    e.gender = getche();

    printf("\n\nPress 1 for ECONOMY CLASS and 2 for BUSSINESS CLASS: ");
    scanf("%d", &clas);
    if (clas == 1)
        strcpy(e.clas, "Economy");
    else
        strcpy(e.clas, "Bussiness");
    e.seatNo = rand() % 500;
    printf("\nYour seat num is: %d\n\n", e.seatNo);

    if (airline==1)
        save = fopen("PIA.DAT", "a");
    else if (airline==2)
        save = fopen("Shaheen.DAT", "a");
    else
        save = fopen("AirBlue.DAT", "a");
    fwrite(&e, sizeof( struct passenger), 1, save);
    fclose(save);

    getch();
}
```

and this is for updating the record

```
void update()
    int  i = 1, count = 0, clas, record = 0;
    int seat, airline;
    struct passenger se;
    printf("\n\n\nSelect your flight:");
    printf("\n1. PIA\n2. Shaheen\n3. Air Blue\n\nEnter Choice:");
    scanf("%d", &airline);

    if (airline == 1)
        updateR = fopen("PIA.DAT", "r+");
    else if (airline == 2)
        updateR = fopen("Shaheen.DAT", "r+");
    else
        updateR = fopen("AirBlue.DAT", "r+");

    if (updateR == NULL)
    {
        printf("File not found.");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nEnter Your Seat No: ");
        scanf("%d", &seat);
        while (!feof(updateR))
        {
            fread(&se, sizeof(struct passenger), 1, updateR);
            if (se.seatNo == seat)
            {
                printf("\nEnter Name:");
                scanf("%s", &e.name);

                printf("\nEnter Age:");
                scanf("%d", &e.age);

                printf("\nEnter Your Gender (M/F): ");
                e.gender = getche();

                printf("\n\nPress 1 for ECONOMY CLASS and 2 for BUSSINESS CLASS: ");
                scanf("%d", &clas);
                if (clas == 1)
                    strcpy(e.clas, "Economy");
                else
                    strcpy(e.clas, "Bussiness");
                fseek(updateR,sizeof(struct passenger)* record, SEEK_END);
                fwrite(&e, sizeof(&e), 1, updateR);
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose(updateR);
    }
    getch();
}
```

Comment: Please provide more information. What is the code supposed to do? What output do you expect? And what output (if any) do you actually get? This kind of context helps readers to help you.

Comment: I'm not sure about these 2 lines

fread(&se, sizeof(struct passenger), 1, updateR);
if (se.seatNo == seat)

It looks like you assume your fread will automatically put the line information into the correct field of the structure (se.seatNo). I'd investigate that first just to check it's working correctly.

Comment: @honk. I want this to search the record according to seat number and if user wants to update his/her record then he/she can update it easily through seat number

Comment: Tell me where you have created and used the variable ***updateR*** please.  Assume it has either file global, or `extern` scope?  By the way, the statement `while (!feof(updateR))` is rarely a good way to read a file.

Comment: @ryyker.. it is a global File type pointer..

Comment: @AmmarBukhari: You should [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28864056/edit) your question in order to improve it instead of providing additional information in the comment section.

Comment: `sizeof(&e)` -> `sizeof(struct e)`  assuming you are trying to get the size of the struct

Comment: The line: `fwrite(&e, sizeof(&e), 1, updateR);` is attempting to write binary data to a file opened for text.  _and_, its arguments are not exactly correct.  _Is the record binary, or is it text_?

Comment: @ryyker - what should I do can you please help me with that?

Comment: I'm curious why you called that variable `clas` rather than `class`. Could it be that you're compiling your C code with a C++ compiler (which would treat `class` as a keyword)? You can do that if you like, but if you're programming in C you really should use a C compiler.

Comment: Addressed how you _could_ write and read to to a record, and store information into a struct in an answer below.  (I do not know how your file is formatted, so made some guesses and assumptions.)

Comment: Well !! The problem was in the mode of reading/writing the file. I was working with binary file and was not using the binary mode. Anyways thanks guys for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There's quite some information missing for a full analysis. But at first glance you're seeking from the end of the file. You're using SEEK_END. Normally you should use SEEK_SET.

Comment: @AmmarBukhari: `SEEK_END` is definitely wrong. You're trying to seek past the end of the file. Probably `fseek()` is failing, but (and this is very important) you're not checking whether it succeeded or failed. Read the documentation for `fseek` to find out how to determine that, and test for it.

Answer (score 0):

`scanf` does NOT need the address-of operator when scanning strings.

So where you have:

```
scanf("%s", &e.name);
```

You really should have:

```
scanf("%s", e.name);
```

Comment: @AmmarBukhari: Yes, it probably would -- but the `&` is still incorrect. `scanf` with `"%s"` expects an argument of type `char*`, which is the type of `e.name` after the implicit array-to-pointer conversion. `&e.name` is also a pointer value, and points to the same memory location, but it's of type `char (*)[20]` (pointer to array of 20 `char`s). Strictly speaking, `scanf("%s", &e.name);` has undefined behavior. Some compilers might warn you about this. abelenky: This does not answer the OP's question; it's a valid point, but it's not the cause of the problem. It would be a good comment.

Comment: @KeithThompson:  Since OP's "question" is basically, *"When I try this code it doesn't work at all."*, who is to say this isn't the problem??   I don't think he gave enough info about the problem for us to know what we're supposed to be fixing.

Comment: @abelenky: The I suggest that *you* don't know enough to post an answer. Given the way pointers and variadic functions are implemented by almost all C compilers, dropping the `&` will almost certainly not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening a text file, and writing the contents of a struct *, that may not work the way you intended.  I do not know what your file format is, you have not specified it.
Assume a comma separated variable formatted file with one record per line.  It could look like this:

```
Alaska, Jones, 23, 1, First, 12
NW, Smith, 12, 1, No, 34
...
```

***Then, the code to write and read*** from that file could look like this:

```
typedef struct passenger
{
    char airline[20];
    char name[20];
    int age;
    char gender[2];//note re-definition from your original
    char clas[10];
    int seatNo;

}E;

void UpdateRecord(char *path, char *record);
void ReadRecord(char *path, E *db, int record);
int getLines(char *path);

int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp = {0};
    char line[80] = {"Alaska2, Jones2, 23, M, First, 12\n"};
    E e;

    UpdateRecord(".\\new.dat", line);
    ReadRecord(".\\new.dat", &e, 1); //Get first line
    ReadRecord(".\\new.dat", &e, getLines(".\\new.dat")); //Get last line

    return 0;
}
void UpdateRecord(char *path, char *record)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "a");
    if(fp)
    {
        fputs(record, fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

void ReadRecord(char *path, E *db, int record)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
    char line[80];
    char *buf = {0};
    while(fgets(line, 80, fp))
    {
        if(++i == record)
        {
            //get e.airline
            buf = strtok(line, " ,\n");
            if(buf) strcpy(db->airline, buf);
            //get e.name
            buf = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");
            if(buf) strcpy(db->name, buf);
            //get e.age
            buf = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");
            if(buf) db->age = atoi(buf);
            //get e.gender
            buf = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");
            if(buf) strcpy(db->gender, buf);
            //get e.clas
            buf = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");
            if(buf) strcpy(db->clas, buf);
            //get e.seatNo
            buf = strtok(NULL, " ,\n");
            if(buf) db->seatNo = atoi(buf); 
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int getLines(char *path)
{
    int lines = 0;
    char line[80];
    FILE *fp = fopen(path, "r");
    if(fp)
    {
        while(fgets(line, 80, fp))
        {
            lines++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    }
    return lines;
}
```

Comment: Thank you.. The problem was with opening and writing to binary file. I tried with "wb" and "rb" file mode my code started working. Thanks once again